# Using params to pass values to a switch in a while loop

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to write a script that sits in a while loop. The goal is to launch the function by typing test. You would then be able to type "s" and pass a value to it onto the switch in the while loop.

```
PS > test
PS > s hello
hello passed
```

Here is what I have done so far:

```
function test{
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
[Parameter(ParameterSetName="s", ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][string[]]$s
)
while($true){
$x = Read-Host
switch($x){
s {
Write-Host $s "passed"
break
}
default {"False"}
}
}
}
```

Please let me know where my logic is off.

Currently I am able to set x equal to s and here is what I get.

```
PS > test
PS > s
passed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.

The `$s` parameter doesn't do/hold anything, because you don't actually pass a parameter argument to `test`.

The `break` statement inside the `switch` is completely redundant since `switch` doesn't support statement fall-through in PowerShell. Assuming that you want to break out of the `while` loop, you'll have to [label the loop and break statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break) (see example below)

Finally, since you expect the input in each iteration of the `while` loop to consist of two parts (in your example `s` and then `hello`), you'll need to split `$x` into two:

```
$first,$second = $x -split '\s',2
```

and then `switch($x)`, so we end up with something like:

```
function test
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()

    # label the while loop "outer"
    :outer while($true){
        $x = Read-Host

        # split $x into two parts
        $first,$second = $x -split '\s',2

        # switch evaluating the first part
        switch($first){
            s {
                # output second part of input
                Write-Host $second "passed"

                # explicitly break out of the "outer" loop
                break outer
            }
            default {
                Write-Host "False"
            }
        }
    }
}
```